# Wrapper with keyword-argument change between RegulaFalsi and Newton-Raphson in Python

Tags: python

I want to write a code with kwargs and the possibility to change between Regula Falsi and Newton-Raphson to get the zero of a function.

My problem is that I do not know how I can integrate the newton step into this because I have other arguments like the starting point, not an interval like it is with at RegulaFalsi.

I intentionally let the space free after the Newton parts btw.

Thanks in advance! Best, Robin.

The beginning:

```
import numpy

def Solve(interval, **kwargs):
    if len(kwargs) == 0:
        print("Methode is not defined")
        return 0
    elif len(kwargs) > 1:
        print("Too much optional parameters")
        return 0
    for key in kwargs:
        if kwargs[key] == "Newton":
        
        elif kwargs[key] == "Regulafalsi":
            for i in range(25):
                interval = regulafalsi_step(interval)
            fx = f(interval[0])
            fy = f(interval[1])
            z = (interval[0] * fy - interval[1] * fx)/(fy - fx)
        else:
            print("Solver: unknown parameter", kwargs.values())
            return 0
        print(f"Zero at: {z}")
    
      
def f(x):
    return numpy.exp(x)-x-2
        
def newton_step(i):

def regulafalsi_step(i):
    fx = f(i[0])
    fy = f(i[1])
    z = (i[0] * fy - i[1] * fx)/(fy - fx)
    if ((fx >= 0) == (f(z) >= 0)):
        return (z, i[1])

    return (i[0], z)

Solve((0, 3), methode="Regulafalsi")
Solve((0, 3), methode="Newton")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*args` to accept unnamed parameters :

```py
def Solve(*args, **kwargs):
    method = kwargs['methode']
    if method == "Newton":
        starting_point = args[0]
        print(f"solving with {method} using {starting_point=!r} ...")
        # do something here ...
        z = 14

    elif method == "Regulafalsi":
        interval = args[0]
        print(f"solving with {method} using {interval=!r} ...")
        # do something here ...
        z = 29

    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(f"{kwargs.get('methode')=!r}")

    print(f"Zero at: {z}")


Solve((0, 3), methode="Regulafalsi")
# solving with Regulafalsi using interval=(0, 3) ...
# Zero at: 29

Solve(14.7, methode="Newton")
# solving with Newton using starting_point=14.7 ...
# Zero at: 14
```

The `Solve` function expects that the first argument passed to it will be an interval when it is using the Regulafalsi method, while it will have to be a starting point when using the Newton method. You can expect more parameters, just get them from `args[1]`, `args[2]`, ...

But I would suggest to instead define two different functions :

```py
def Solve_with_Newton(starting_point):
    print(f"solving with Newton using {starting_point=!r} ...")
    # do something here ...
    z = 14
    print(f"Zero at: {z}")


def Solve_with_Regulafalsi(interval):
    print(f"solving with Regulafalsi using {interval=!r} ...")
    # do something here ...
    z = 29
    print(f"Zero at: {z}")


Solve_with_Regulafalsi((0, 3))
# solving with Regulafalsi using interval=(0, 3) ...
# Zero at: 29

Solve_with_Newton(14.7)
# solving with Newton using starting_point=14.7 ...
# Zero at: 14
```

It has the same output than before, the code is shorter, there is no need to handle the case where the method's name is incorrect, the arguments are explicit, ...
Although it is possible to do it with `kwargs`, I suggest against it.